# Output doesn't show when the page is reloaded

Tags: php, file

I have created a small application which writes the contents of the `$email` variable into the file `mailadressen.txt`. If the file exists, the message "Email address already exists" *(E-Mail-Adresse bereits vorhanden)* appears. If I change the mail adress and reload the page then it doesn't output nothing. But if I reload it again with the new email address if displays the message "Email address already exists" again.

Can someone give me a tip why it doesn't output anything on the first reload but only on the second reload?

```
<?php
    $email = "Kevin@duck.ente";

    // open file and read & write
    $handle = fopen ("mailadressen.txt", "a+");

    while ( $inhalt = fgets ($handle, 4096 ))
    {
      $inhalt = trim ( $inhalt );
      echo "<li> |". $inhalt ."| </li>";
      if ( $inhalt == $email)
      {
        echo "E-Mail-Adresse bereits vorhanden";
        continue;
      }
    }

    fwrite($handle, $email);

    // new line
    fwrite($handle, "\r\n");

    fclose($handle);
    ?>
```

Comment: What is reload? You might have a cache issue here. Call your script with arbitrary numbers like myscript.php?21 and change the number every call as realoding might be cached in your browser.

Comment: Add this to the beginning of your code. `ini_set("display_errors", true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` So you can see the errors.

Comment: Hello thank you for you answers

@Samuel I mean reloading of the page. And no it's not a caching issue.

@Y U N OWORK there are no errors

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you say you "reload"? As I said clicking the reload button in a browser may display you cached content.

Comment: You check and echo the added email address before writing it into file so PHP being server side techology you need to refresh the page for the message to appear. Try checking the email, add it into file if it not exists, and do the email already exists message last. (Or look into AJAX solutions.) (BTW: Does your code add duplicate addresses since you seem to always write the address into file? Is this what you want to do?)

Comment: @Samuel I'm pretty sure the browser don't show me the cached content. I also deactivate the cache on my browser. 

And when I say "reload" i mean the reload button in a browser.

Comment: @ZZ-bb Thank you!! now i see the problem. 
Now it doens't matter if the if the file have duplicate email addresses because i'm just practicing for my own. But I expand my application and make it better. Now it just write the email into my txt file and thats enough right now

Comment: Great, I added an answer where duplicate addresses are not added to the file. It seems that you got idea so you can pretty much do whatever you like with duplicates. Gotta go now, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution based on my comment.

```
$email = "Kevin@duck.ente";

// open file and read & write
$handle = fopen ("mailadressen.txt", "a+");

while ( $inhalt = fgets ($handle, 4096 )){

  $inhalt = trim ( $inhalt );
  echo "<li> |". $inhalt ."| </li>";

  if ( $inhalt == $email){
    $email_exists = true;
    $msg = "E-Mail-Adresse bereits vorhanden";
    continue;
  }
}

//echo the message if email already exists
if(isset($email_exists) && $email_exists === true){
  echo $msg;
}
  else{
    //let's write only non existing email to the file
    fwrite($handle, $email);

    // new line
    fwrite($handle, "\r\n");

    echo "Wrote new email: " . $email . " into the mailadressen.txt file.";
  }

fclose($handle);
```